# stop Array sort to remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, duplicates, date-sorting

Using expressionengine I have couple of loops like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries ........} <--- CMS Loop starts --->

 $data ="{event_day}.{event_month}.{event_year }"; // will output 19.21.2013 
      $titlu = htmlentities("{title}"); // string
      $link = "{adresa_externa}"; // website
      $arrContent3[strtotime($data)] = substr($data, 0, 5)." - ". "<a href='$link'> " . $titlu ."    </a>";
  {/exp:channel:entries} <--- cms loops ends --- >
```

After the array we have the following code:

```
<---- outputing in chronological order based on day year month --->
    <?php 
    ksort($arrContent3) ;
    echo html_entity_decode(implode("</li><li>", $arrContent));
    ?>
```

The problem is that if there exist 2 things with the exact same date. Only one will show up in the list.

I have no idea why :(

Comment: You are using `strtotime($data)` as an array key. Arrays can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: and what do you suggest in this key ? I want that events in the same day to get into the array. :(

Comment: I have no idea what you are using the key for, so I can't predict the consequences of changing it. But you know what the problem is, so you should be able to decide on your own.

Comment: I have to bring together multiple arrays of events from different sources and then output all of them based on day and month

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you set an array entry $arrContent[strtotime($data)] and you already have an entry for the same value of $data, then the second overwrites the first.

So instead of assigning a scalar value to $arrContent[strtotime($data)], assign an array element,

```
$arrContent[strtotime($data)][] = expression;
```

Do the ksort() in the same way as you have, to get them in date order, but then loop over the array leaves to make a one dimensional array,

```
foreach($arrContent as $arrDateContent) {
    foreach($arrDateContent as $content) {
        $arrContentAll[] = $content;
    }
}
```

You can then do the echo,

```
echo html_entity_decode(implode("</li><li>", $arrContentAll));
```

Edit:

So the code (from the original question) becomes:

```
{exp:channel:entries ........} <--- CMS Loop starts --->

 $data ="{event_day}.{event_month}.{event_year }"; // will output 19.21.2013 
      $titlu = htmlentities("{title}"); // string
      $link = "{adresa_externa}"; // website
      $arrContent3[strtotime($data)][] = substr($data, 0, 5)." - ". "<a href='$link'> " . $titlu ."    </a>";
  {/exp:channel:entries} <--- cms loops ends --- >
```

and then for the second part,

```
<---- outputing in chronological order based on day year month --->
    <?php 
    ksort($arrContent3) ;
    foreach($arrContent3 as $arrDateContent) {
        foreach($arrDateContent as $content) {
            $arrContentAll[] = $content;
        }
    }
    echo html_entity_decode(implode("</li><li>", $arrContentAll));
    ?>
```

Comment: If I add to all the 3 loops the code it shows the doubles but now it is no more chronological ordered by day and month

Comment: @AgheorghieseiAndrei-Klauss Not sure what you mean so I've added in an edited version of your original code to be clearer what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest with your existing code would be to set `$i = 0;` before the loop, then:

```
$arrContent3[strtotime($data).$i++] = substr($data, 0, 5)." - ". "<a href='$link'> " . $titlu ."    </a>";
```

Though I have no idea how you go from `$arrContent3` to `$arrContent`.

Comment: What do you mean by Though I have no idea how you go from $arrContent3 to $arrContent.

Comment: In your template code you have `$arrContent3[strtotime($data)]` and then in the PHP code you have `ksort($arrContent) ;`.  Two diff variables.

Comment: I did try your code, but remember i have multiple arrays like above. It was my mistake in the code. I edited IS $arrContent3 at the output  arrContent3 , but if I put at each array the code you propose, the overall result is not ordered anymore.

Comment: I thought of the same $i++ thing but the (hyperthetical) problem is that because this is appending to an integer it will nearly always work, but fail if there are dates that result in timestamps with different numbers of digits (like 9... and 10...)